# Weird issue while calling get request web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET WebAPI project, which has Get API - "appointment/available" defined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using AppointmentScheduler;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

[RoutePrefix("appointment")]
public class AppointmentController : ApiController
{
    #region [ Properties ]
    [Dependency]
    public IAppointmentScheduler AppointmentScheduler { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region [ Methods - API ]
    [Route("available")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAvailableAppointments(string agentEmailId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
        try {
            return base.Ok(this.AppointmentScheduler.GetAppointments(agentEmailId, startDate, endDate));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            return base.InternalServerError(exception);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

However, on running the solution and calling the API from Fiddler as "GET" request I get following error:

> HTTP 405 Error - The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

On sending the same request as "POST" I get HTTP - 200  response. Even though my method was never called (the breakpoint on the API method was never hit)

I looked into previous query on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api). But none of the answers seems to be solve my issue.

Interestingly, unless I'm crazy the exact code was working for me sometime back.

I think the issue started coming up when I tried to open the solution initially built on VS 2013 on VS 2015. I feel, only after that the solution started giving issue in both the IDEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was calling a API with wrong url - Instead of calling "appointment/available", I was calling "api/appointment/available" by mistake.
Ended up wasting my morning on a non-issue.

However, one thing which I still could not understand it why it returned Http Status 405 for "Get" request and 200 for "Post" and NOT "404" when the API did not exist.

**Update:**

Got the issue, there was one more method in the same controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult BlockAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        try {
            return base.Ok(this.AppointmentScheduler.BlockAppointment(appointment));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            return base.InternalServerError(exception);
        }
    }
```

This API call for above method was: POST api/appointment. So, I was actually calling above method and not the indented method from Fiddler and never realized that.