# (405) Method not allowed for API and Website on same domain and server

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, api

I have a website which I am trying to make a request via web API to the database. The API basically updates a bit field (in this case from 0 to 1).

**Error:**

This is all from the console.

```
OPTIONS  http://123.123.123.123:12345/project/webapi.svc/category/api/1/do/something 405 (Method Not Allowed)

send @ jquery-1.12.4.js:10254
ajax @ jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
click @ PageModal.js:10
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.js:12443
dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.js:4878

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://123.123.123.123:12345/project/webapi.svc/category/api/1/do/something. Response to page.aspx preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://123.123.123.123' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

**Request:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://123.123.123.123:12345/project/webapi.svc/category/api/1/do/something",  //method Name 
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: ticketId }),
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (msg)
        {
            alert("error: " + msg.status);
        }
 });
```

The only thing I can find on this are people who are trying to access the API from a different domain but I am on the same domain. I also have an iOS app which can POST without an issues however it seems the website is having issues.

**Question:**

How can I fix this 405 error? What is happening here?

Comment: look into CORS - that's the problem you're having.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: Aren't those links  dealing with cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an api backend problem you probably need to add permission to post in your api controller

[405 method not allowed web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api)

Comment: I am able to POST from the iOS app to the Web API though.