# Side effects of disabling WebDAVModule in ASP.NET MVC WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, webdav

In my WebAPI application, I faced similar issue of [405 method not allowed web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api)
and this issue; [Asp.NET Web API - 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed - how to set handler mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854602/asp-net-web-api-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-how?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I had to disable WebDAVModule in my web.config like below;

```
 <modules>
 <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
 </modules>

 <handlers>
 <remove name="WebDAV"/>
 </handlers>
```

I do not depend explicitly to this module, but I am just wondering that would disabling this module could create any significant performance/security problems? I checked documentation below, but could not find anything specific to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-7/what39s-new-for-webdav-and-iis-7

Comment: Many IIS servers don't even have WebDAV installed, so merely deleting it from your config file won't have any harm. It would improve performance and security, as IIS loads one less module.

Comment: The only downside really would be if your users use WebDAV for anything in your site...

Comment: Thanks for confirming on this @LexLi.