# Getting 405 status Error when trying to consume POST method of web/Api in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to consume post method of web/api which takes string as parameter, but getting 405 Error : Api Controller Name: Getdata Action Method Name : postdata

please help to identify error.

```
public bool postdata(string fn)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59968/api/Getdata");
                var task = client.PostAsJsonAsync("Getdata", fn);
                task.Wait();

                var res = task.Result;
                if(res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

`[HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult postdata(string p)
        {
            using (var context = new MediaEntities())
            {
                mediatable m = new mediatable()
                {
                    media_path = p,
                    is_active = true
                };
                context.mediatable.Add(m);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok();
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used action method names instead of controller name else provide details of your api.

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59968/api/{controller_name}");

//HTTP POST
var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync("controller_name", fn);
```

This [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consume-web-api-post-method-in-aspnet-mvc) might help you.

Comment: have you tried above code replacing "controller_name" with you web api controller name.

Comment: check your routing, try searching on SO you will find answer. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api