# 405 Method Not Allowed - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs

I am receiving a 405 Method Not Allowed error for an ASP.Net WebAPI service in Elastic Container Service when accessed via Postman. This error **does not** occur when running the container locally using Docker or using the Swagger UI via a browser.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Log into the application
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/v1/authenticate")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]LoginDto loginAttempt)
        {
          ...
        }
```

I don't know where to start with this as it's only happening in the cloud, and only when accessing the API via Postman. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [405 method not allowed Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api)

Comment: It looks like you're maybe doing a `http` request and you need to do `https`

Comment: Make sure from postman you are hitting with post method. Not with get method. Does this solve your issue ?

Comment: No unfortunately. I am 100% using POST.