# .NET Core 7, Error: 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

In .NET Core 7 Web API, which utilizes Entity Framework, I encountered an error when making HTTP PUT and DELETE requests on the server. However, the code works correctly when running locally.

The specific error received is "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed."

APIs:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("DeleteCode")]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DeleteCode(int Id)
{
}

and

[Route("EditCode")]
[HttpPut]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult EditCode(CodeDTO model)
{
}
```

Please note that my database is hosted on Plesk.

I tried adding the suggested code to the server's webconfig file, but unfortunately, it did not resolve the issue.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: try this <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

Comment: Also can you show how you are cvalling the web api, are u passing json or what? check this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api

Comment: Thanks! Your first comment is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

check tow things

```
1- using System.Web.Mvc; // Wrong namespace for HttpGet attribute !!!!!!!!!

2- using System.Web.Http; // Correct namespace for HttpGet attribute !!!!!!!!!
```

also routing

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetAllRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}"/*,
    defaults: new { action = "Get" }*/ // this was causing the issue
);
```

check the routing also.

```
 <system.webServer> <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"> <remove name="WebDAVModule" /> </modules> </system.webServer>
```