# .NET Core 8, Error: 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-8

In an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, Blazor WASM Framework, I encounter an error when making HTTP `POST` requests on IIS. However, the code works correctly when running locally.

The specific error is

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

API:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http;

[Route("api/upload")]
[ApiController]
public class UploadController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost, HttpGet, HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        var uploadPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uploads");

        if (!Directory.Exists(uploadPath)) 
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, file.FileName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
@code {
    private List<IBrowserFile> selectedFiles = new List<IBrowserFile>();
    private bool uploading = false;
    private string successMessage;
    private string errorMessage;

    private void HandleSelectedFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())
        {
            selectedFiles.Add(file);
        }
    }

    private async Task UploadFiles()
    {
        uploading = true;
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        foreach (var file in selectedFiles)
        {
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
            content.Add(fileContent, "files", file.Name);
        }

        var response = await Http.PostAsync("api/upload", content);
        uploading = false;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            successMessage = $"{selectedFiles.Count} files uploaded successfully.";
            selectedFiles.Clear(); 
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Error occurred while uploading files.";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding the suggested code to the server's `web.config` file, but unfortunately, it did not resolve the issue.

And WebDAVModule is not currently installed on IIS.

Let me explain the steps I have taken:

1. WebDAVModule

```
<system.webServer> 
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"> 
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" /> 
    </modules> 
</system.webServer>
```

2. Disconnect the firewall and ports on the server
3. IIS HTTP verbs allowed
4. Allow all folder security permissions in IIS
5. I referred to the article below, but I couldn't solve it.
   [405 method not allowed Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api)

Comment: I suggest you check the handler mapping's aspnetcore module's request restrictions to check if its verbs doesn't contain the post method and request filtering check post is allowed. Image like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqHYA.png.